# Connection Pool for rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having this issue with rails 5 rc1. Does anyone have any idea how to configure it in the environment files and what is the default connection pool size for rails 5 active record.

```
   Puma caught this error: could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use (ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError)
    /home/bsethi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:202:in `block in wait_poll'
    /home/bsethi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:193:in `loop'
    /home/bsethi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:193:in `wait_poll'
    /home/bsethi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:154:in `internal_poll'
    /home/bsethi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:278:in `internal_poll'
    /home/bsethi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:148:in `block in poll'
```

Comment: Both answers are right but is there a way to put it in the config file?

Comment: I updated my answer. Basically speaking it's just a continuation of @Alessandro Caetano's answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In all rails versions I had used connection pool configured in config/database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

So just increase it:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 10
  timeout: 5000
```

Let me know if it will be helpful.

**UPDATE**

It seems it's not so straightforward to put your values to environment/*.rb files.
The closest way IMHO is to use ENV variables as @Alessandro Caetano suggests.

Community has a gem for such operations: [rais-dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)

You could just create `.env.*` files for each environment and then dotenv will load it accordingly.

Here is an example:

```
# .env.development
main_db_database=main_db_development
main_db_pool=5
main_db_host=localhost
main_db_port=3306
main_db_user=user
main_db_password=password
```

Then in your database.tml

```
development: &main_db
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: <%= ENV['main_db_database'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV['main_db_pool'] ? ENV['main_db_pool'].to_i : 5 %>
  host: <%= ENV['main_db_host'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['main_db_port'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['main_db_username'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['main_db_password'] %>
```

Comment: `.to_i` doesn't appear to be necessary on the pool size https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L243

Answer (score 6):

You can set the connection pool limit in your config/database.yml, like this:

```
production:
   url:  <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
   pool: <%= ENV["DB_POOL"] || ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>
```

Comment: Do you just add `ENV["DB_POOL"] = x` to the boot.rb file?

Comment: @NicolasGuillaume you can set these variables on your `~/.bashrc` file using `export DB_POOL = 5` and so on. After that, you need to`source ~/.bashrc` to apply the changes to your current terminal session or open a new terminal, then your rails app should be able to recognize the environment variable. If you don't like putting enviroment variables on your bashrc, you can use a gem, as @retgoat sugests.

Comment: You can also use https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro which stores unique environment variables in `config/application.yml` and can raise errors if variables are missing.